# Codename One Slider marker

Tags: mobile, codenameone

I have some questions about sliders,
Im using a slider and i want a marker to be present on it like:
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-HDNFnyRU2Cw/TcuMbBaL70I/AAAAAAAAAGc/7eWN1qnZbAw/s1600/seek.JPG
it draws the image at the bottom of the slider, not on top of it, searched for a setThumbImagePosition or something like that ,but didnt find it, is there a way to use sliders with markers on the top of them?(like the image shown) 
Is there a way to show divisions on the slider?(for example this)
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/channguyen/range-slider-view/master/screenshots/sc.png
Whats the best practice to create thicker sliders?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/its-full-of-stars-terse-commands.html) notice that in order to create the stars effect properly we wrap the slider in a flow layout to prevent it from growing. You can use background images just like we do in the stars slider but you need to place the slider in a flow layout of similar layout that doesn't let it grow beyond its preferred size.